# Sequences in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sequence

Is there a simple function in ruby to create sequences? For example, I want a sequence from 1 to 100 incrementing by 3. So

```
Function(1,100,increment = 3) = [1,4,7,10, ...,97,100]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step) generates another enumerator with given step.

say `(1..100).step(3).to_a` would be `[1,4,7, ... , 97, 100]`

alternatively 
[`Numeric#step(limit,step)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step) does similar things,

say `1.step(100,3).to_a`